# How to get the WebService address dynamically from the txt file in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, forms, web-services, reference

I'm building a small application and I'm using WebService in it. I was using a local WebService just by adding its reference in my project's solution manager.

My question is: is it possible to get the WebService url address dynamically, for example from a .txt file?

Thanks for every help.

Edit:

I want to change the WebService url address in my app's code. After that, the url will be placed in a .txt file and the app will get it from there.

Comment: Yes it is possible, have you tried to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the url of a web service by reading from the web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513609/change-the-url-of-a-web-service-by-reading-from-the-web-config)

Comment: I want to change the WebService url address in my app's code. After that, the url will be placed in a .txt file and the app will get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any url for your WebService client using the clients constructor. There you can provide the url to use:

```
var client = new YourServiceClient("<bindingName>", new EndpointAddress("<your url>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513609/change-the-url-of-a-web-service-by-reading-from-the-web-config). They are accessing the URL from config file, instead of text while.